# Android Emulator Inverted screen Glitch

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

[image]

Created new Virtual device many times as well as wiped dGraphics:stalled HXAM.

**Emulator:**
Graphics: Automatic( Same Issue in both)
RAM: 2048 MB
VM Heap: 512 MB

**System:**
Total memory:12.00 GB
Processor name:Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz

Comment: Please check device rotation in emulator properties.

Comment: Hi Jaymin,
My emulator is showing way many glitches that it shouldn't show like.
The google logo just vibrates and doesn't go ahead now.

Comment: Okay then try delete system image and download again.

Comment: I did that still not working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revision 27.0.5 (January 2018)

ANGLE for rendering on Windows is now disabled by default.

If ANGLE works better for you, you can re-enable it with command line flag -gpu angle_indirect. Or, open the Extended controls window, navigate to Settings > Advanced, and select ANGLE D3D11 for the OpenGL ES renderer setting.